# Filter a list of queries on datetime field gives warning

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am querying a model from my ORM in Django like the following:

```
client = Client.objects.get(pk=cname).user
items = Allotment.objects.filter(sales_order__owner=client).order_by('-id')
```

and want to filter it by datetime that I am getting as parameters from URL

```
URL:  GET /allotment-reports/?cname=3&to=2020-07-30+15:07&from=2020-07-01+15:07
```

So I tried this:

```
f = request.GET['from']
t = request.GET['to']

items = items.filter(dispatch_date__range = [f,t])
```

but keep getting the warning:

> RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField Allotment.dispatch_date received a
> naive datetime (2020-07-30 15:07:00) while time zone support is
> active.   RuntimeWarning)

I am using the same format as I have used in my models, then Why is it showing the warning?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#use-tz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the variables **`f`** and **`t`** are ***not [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime) objects "with [`tzinfo`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.tzinfo)"***, they are just ***strings***.

Something like this would wipeout the warning,

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime

dt_format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:'  # or suitable format
f = datetime.strptime(request.GET['from'], dt_format).replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC)
t = datetime.strptime(request.GET['to'], dt_format).replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC)

items = items.filter(dispatch_date__range=[f, t])
```

Comment: ValueError: time data '2020-07-01 13:07' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:'
I am getting this error

Comment: In my settings.py I have this format `DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ',)`

Comment: You may need to change the value of `dt_format` to the desired or compatible date format